# Configure Client commands from command line

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, ibm-cloud-private

In IBM Cloud Private EE, I need to go to the Web UI `User > Configure client`, copy the `kubectl` config commands and then run these 5 commands on my client machine.

I deployed the IBM Cloud private EE on 5 VMs and have access to the master node. I am wondering if there is a way to capture these `kubectl config` commands directly from the docker containers without having a need to go to the Web UI.

For example: I did not want to download the `kubectl` client from google (as I just want to use same `kubectl` version which is in the ICP containers) and I used the following command to get it from the container itself.

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data -e LICENSE=accept \
   ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.1-ee \
   cp -r /usr/local/bin/kubectl /data
```

Then, I copied this to all VM guests so that I could access `kubectl` from any guest.

```
chmod +x kubectl
for host in $(awk '/192.168.142/ {print $3}' /etc/hosts)
do
   scp kubectl $host:/bin
done
```

Where - `192.168.142` is the subnet of my VM guests.

But, I could not figure out how to get `Configure Client` commands without having to go to the Web UI. I need this to automate client `kubectl` command so that my environment is ready for `kubectl` commands through simple scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)** to automate those steps.

For instance, [`IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/Vagrantfile`](https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/ba600e9c08d5bd9fd784e1b209a07ef597052a7f/Vagrantfile#L659-L666) has this section:

```
install_kubectl = <<SCRIPT
echo "Pulling #{image_repo}/kubernetes:v#{k8s_version}..."
sudo docker run -e LICENSE=#{license} --net=host -v /usr/local/bin:/data #{image_repo}/kubernetes:v#{k8s_version} cp /kubectl /data &> /dev/null
kubectl config set-credentials icpadmin --username=admin --password=admin &> /dev/null
kubectl config set-cluster icp --server=http://127.0.0.1:8888 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true &> /dev/null
kubectl config set-context icp --cluster=icp --user=admin  --namespace=default &> /dev/null
kubectl config use-context icp &> /dev/null
SCRIPT
```

See more at "[Kubernetes, IBM Cloud Private, and Vagrant, oh my!](https://medium.com/ibm-cloud/kubernetes-ibm-cloud-private-and-vagrant-oh-my-cedc0758036f)", from **[Tim Pouyer](https://twitter.com/tpouyer)**.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I would like to use Vagrant but I like VMware Workstation. In order for me to use Vagrant for VMware workstation, I need a buy a license of $70 and I need separate license on any other machine where I run this.

Thank you for the tip but again you are using --password option in using set-credentials and I want to use token. Do you know how could I get that token without using the password?

Comment: @Vikram do those VMs have to be VMware? Why not VirtualBox?

Comment: @Vikram Regarding your question in your comment, why not `kubectl config set-credentials user --token={token}`? As in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe25b4ef-ea6a-4d86-a629-6f87ccf4649e/entry/Configuring_the_Kubernetes_CLI_by_using_service_account_tokens1?lang=en

Comment: Tim - I guess that I am not used to Virtual Box as I had been using VMware Workstation since 2001. It is very stable and has a very good performance. It is similar to using IBM Db2 vs MariaDB. Just a personal preference.

Comment: Tim - the link you gave is what I was looking for - how to get service account token from a running container - thank you. I guess that I did not use right keywords to google it.

Answer (score 0):

@VonC provided useful tips. This is how the service account token can be obtained.

Get the token from a running container - Tip from this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe25b4ef-ea6a-4d86-a629-6f87ccf4649e/entry/Configuring_the_Kubernetes_CLI_by_using_service_account_tokens1?lang=en).

```
RUNNIGCONTAINER=$(docker ps | grep k8s_cloudiam-apikeys_auth | awk '{print $1}')
TOKEN=$(docker exec -t $RUNNIGCONTAINER cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
```

I already know the name of the IBM Cloud Private cluster name, master node and the default user name. The only missing link was the token. Please note that the script used by Tim is using password and the only difference was - I wanted to use token instead of the password.

So use the scripts.

```
kubectl config set-cluster ${CLUSTERNAME}.icp --server=https://$MASTERNODE:8001 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config set-context ${CLUSTERNAME}.icp-context --cluster=${CLUSTERNAME}.icp
kubectl config set-credentials admin --token=$TOKEN
kubectl config set-context ${CLUSTERNAME}.icp-context --user=$DEFAULTUSERNAME --namespace=default
kubectl config use-context ${CLUSTERNAME}.icp-context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# get token
icp_auth_token=`curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
    -d "grant_type=password&username=${myuser}&password=${mypass}&scope=openid" \
    https://${icp_server}:8443/idprovider/v1/auth/identitytoken --insecure | \
    sed 's/{//g;s/}//g;s/\"//g' | \
    awk -F ':' '{print $7}'`

# setup context
kubectl config set-cluster ${icp_server} --server=https://${icp_server}:8001 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true 
kubectl config set-credentials ${icp_server}-user --token=${icp_auth_token}
kubectl config set-context ${icp_server}-context --cluster=${icp_server} --user=${icp_server}-user 
kubectl config use-context ${icp_server}-context
```